# Soma de dados de um array utilizando condição

Tags: php, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e estou fazendo o seguinte teste.

No caso, tenho uma quantidade de registros relativo a queda de links e eu preciso somar esses resultados caso a diferença entre eles seja menor que 24 horas, e apresentar a data de inicio da queda do primeiro registro com o fechamento do ultimo registro neste prazo. Eu até consegui fazer parte do teste e somar os dois primeiros elementos do vetor, mas ao solicitar os demais, ele da erro.

O que pode ser feito neste caso, segue abaixo o trecho do código e a parte que estou empacado

```
<?Php

        error_reporting(E_ERROR);

        $inicio = array("2018-03-02 00:04","2018-03-02 00:25","2018-03-02 01:04","2018-03-02 01:34","2018-03-01 00:24");
        $fechamento = array("2018-03-02 00:19","2018-03-02 00:56","2018-03-02 01:31","2018-03-02 02:00","2018-03-11 00:27");
        $tempo_indisponivel = array("00:08:04","00:05:04","00:02:02","00:07:56","00:03:11");

        $horasLenght = count($inicio); //Conta a quantidade de registros no vetor 

            for($x = 0; $x < $horasLenght; $x++) {
                $y = $x - 1 //Cria um segundo indice para fazer o teste 

                        //Transforma o array de tempo indisponível em segundos 

                        $seg_x = strtotime('1970-01-01'.$tempo_indisponivel[$x].'UTC'); 

                        //Inicia o teste
                        if($y < 0) { 
                            echo $seg_x."____".$x."<b>XXX</b>"; 
                        } else { 
                            echo $seg_x."____".$x."<b>XXX</b>"; 
                            $diferenca = strtotime($inicio[$x]) - strtotime($inicio[$y]);

                            if($diferenca < 86400) {
                                //Aqui que começa a duvida
                            }
                        }



            }




     ?>
```

A duvida está no segundo if que faz o calculo da diferença

NO caso, ele terá que apresentar somente duas linhas

na Primeira linha ele mostraria a posição[1] de inicio, posição[4] de fechamento e somaria as posições de 1 a 4 de tempo indisponivel. 
A segunda linha seria composta com todas posições cinco.

O que pode ser feito neste caso?